# c++ Getting error after compile

Tags: c++, windows, dll, g++, mingw

This is my main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Tokenizer.h"
using namespace std;

int input;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    Tokenizer obj("yeet");
    cout << obj.getString();
    cin >> input;
return 0;
}
```

This is my Tokenizer.h

```
#ifndef TOKENIZER_H
#define TOKENIZER_H
#include <string>

class Tokenizer{
    public:
        Tokenizer(std::string m);
        std::string getString();
    protected:
    private:
        std::string token;
};

#endif // TOKENIZER_H
```

This is my Tokenizer.cpp

```
#include "Tokenizer.h"
#include <string>

Tokenizer::Tokenizer(std::string m){
    token=m;
   //code 
}

std::string Tokenizer::getString(){
    return token;
}
```

when i compile with g++ it works fine and when i open a.exe i get this error.

> The procedure entry point
>   _ZNSt7_cxx1112basic_stringlcSt11char_traitslcESalcEEC1EPKcRKS^_ could not be located in the dynamic link libary c:\"My project path"

(All files are in same folder.)

and i compiled with int without strings it worked fine i guess it is a error with `#include <string>`

Comment: What toolchain/environment is this ? mingw ? cygwin ? other ?

Comment: i am using mingw.

Comment: OK - added a `mingw` tag for you.

Comment: @Ron i am new i do not know how to acces that when i use "g++ Tokenizer.cpp main.cpp" it just completes and creates a a.exe with nothing on cmd

Comment: May be try to compile by with "g++ Tokenizer.cpp main.cpp -std=c++11"

Comment: @Yadhunandana Thanks but still the same error Should i try to reinstall mingw?

Comment: No need to reinstall. I have mingw in my PC. Following command worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mingw You have to explicitly specify libgcc libstdc++ the libraries. Use the following command

`g++ Tokenizer.cpp main.cpp -o main -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++`

Comment: Accept answer if this solves your problem. This worked for me.